# Odoo define income account for this product id15

Tags: odoo, point-of-sale

I need help.

My problem is I can't close a POS session because a product need to define income account.

```
Errortext: please define income account for this product (ID15).
```

In the settings of the product, I can't define anything.

In the product settings/ Accounting is all empty. Maybe the setting is hidden?
I searched in the product settings. But I didn't find where I can define income account.

Answer (score 1):

Odoo will try to get the [income](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/point_of_sale/models/pos_session.py#L1151-L1157) account from the product if defined, otherwise it will use the default account set on the sale journal in the pos settings

The product income account can be set on the product form under the accounting tab or in the product category